# Android FFMPEG video editing operation failed

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I am using FFMPEG in my Android app for video cropping and trimming but when I execute the following command on a specific video. FFMPEG command execution failed and the app crashed.

Command:

```
ffmpeg -y -i "/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/Test-Video.mp4" -crf 19 -color_primaries 1 -color_trc 1 -colorspace 1 -vcodec h264 -acodec aac -ss 00:00:00 -t 00:00:15 -async 1 -vf "crop=540:539:0:0:exact=0 , scale='if(gt(iw,ih),min(640,iw),-2)':'if(gt(iw,ih),-2,min(640,ih))'" "/data/user/0/com.bipin.myapp/cache/Test-Video_16535454525974982000318197164476.mp4"
```

Failure logs:

```
2022-05-26 11:40:52.605 5308-9484/com.bipin.myapp D/[RxCachedThreadScheduler-11;FFmpegUtil#performVideoOperation:151]: Debug - performVideoOperation - Source File: Test-Video.mp4, size: 9.697972297668457 MBs
2022-05-26 11:40:52.605 5308-9484/com.bipin.myapp D/[RxCachedThreadScheduler-11;FFmpegUtil#performVideoOperation:159]: Debug - performVideoOperation - Command: -y -i "/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/Test-Video.mp4" -crf 19 -color_primaries 1 -color_trc 1 -colorspace 1 -vcodec h264 -acodec aac -ss 00:00:00 -t 00:00:15 -async 1 -vf "crop=540:539:0:0:exact=0 , scale='if(gt(iw,ih),min(640,iw),-2)':'if(gt(iw,ih),-2,min(640,ih))'" "/data/user/0/com.bipin.myapp/cache/Test-Video_16535454525974982000318197164476.mp4"
2022-05-26 11:40:52.607 5308-9484/com.bipin.myapp I/mobile-ffmpeg: Loading mobile-ffmpeg.
2022-05-26 11:40:52.617 5308-9484/com.bipin.myapp I/mobile-ffmpeg: Loaded mobile-ffmpeg-min-gpl-arm64-v8a-4.4-lts-20200724.
2022-05-26 11:40:52.619 5308-9485/com.bipin.myapp D/mobile-ffmpeg: Callback thread started.
2022-05-26 11:40:52.620 5308-9485/com.bipin.myapp I/mobile-ffmpeg: ffmpeg version v4.4-dev-416
2022-05-26 11:40:52.620 5308-9485/com.bipin.myapp I/mobile-ffmpeg:  Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
2022-05-26 11:40:52.620 5308-9485/com.bipin.myapp I/mobile-ffmpeg: 
2022-05-26 11:40:52.620 5308-9485/com.bipin.myapp I/mobile-ffmpeg:   built with Android (6454773 based on r365631c2) clang version 9.0.8 (https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/llvm-project 98c855489587874b2a325e7a516b99d838599c6f) (based on LLVM 9.0.8svn)
2022-05-26 11:40:52.620 5308-9485/com.bipin.myapp I/mobile-ffmpeg:   configuration: --cross-prefix=aarch64-linux-android- --sysroot=/files/android-sdk/ndk/21.3.6528147/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot --prefix=/home/taner/Projects/mobile-ffmpeg/prebuilt/android-arm64/ffmpeg --pkg-config=/usr/bin/pkg-config --enable-version3 --arch=aarch64 --cpu=armv8-a --cc=aarch64-linux-android21-clang --cxx=aarch64-linux-android21-clang++ --extra-libs='-L/home/taner/Projects/mobile-ffmpeg/prebuilt/android-arm64/cpu-features/lib -lndk_compat' --target-os=android --enable-neon --enable-asm --enable-inline-asm --enable-cross-compile --enable-pic --enable-jni --enable-optimizations --enable-swscale --enable-shared --enable-v4l2-m2m --disable-outdev=fbdev --disable-indev=fbdev --enable-small --disable-openssl --disable-xmm-clobber-test --disable-debug --enable-lto --disable-neon-clobber-test --disable-programs --disable-postproc --disable-doc --disable-htmlpages --disable-manpages --disable-podpages --disable-txtpages --disable-static --disable-sndio --disable-schannel --disable-securetransport --disable-xlib --disable-cuda --disable-cuvid --disable-nvenc --disable-vaapi --disable-vdpau --disable-videotoolbox --disable-audiotoolbox --disable-appkit --disable-alsa --disable-cuda --disable-cuvid --disable-nvenc --disable-vaapi --disable-vdpau --enable-libx264 --enable-gpl --enable-libxvid --enable-gpl --enable-libx265 --enable-gpl --enable-libvidstab --enable-gpl --disable-sdl2 --enable-zlib --enable-mediacodec
2022-05-26 11:40:52.621 5308-9485/com.bipin.myapp I/mobile-ffmpeg:   libavutil      56. 55.100 / 56. 55.100
2022-05-26 11:40:52.621 5308-9485/com.bipin.myapp I/mobile-ffmpeg:   libavcodec     58. 96.100 / 58. 96.100
2022-05-26 11:40:52.621 5308-9485/com.bipin.myapp I/mobile-ffmpeg:   libavformat    58. 48.100 / 58. 48.100
2022-05-26 11:40:52.622 5308-9485/com.bipin.myapp I/mobile-ffmpeg:   libavdevice    58. 11.101 / 58. 11.101
2022-05-26 11:40:52.622 5308-9485/com.bipin.myapp I/mobile-ffmpeg:   libavfilter     7. 87.100 /  7. 87.100
2022-05-26 11:40:52.622 5308-9485/com.bipin.myapp I/mobile-ffmpeg:   libswscale      5.  8.100 /  5.  8.100
2022-05-26 11:40:52.622 5308-9485/com.bipin.myapp I/mobile-ffmpeg:   libswresample   3.  8.100 /  3.  8.100
2022-05-26 11:40:52.638 5308-5308/com.bipin.myapp D/InputMethodManager: startInputInner - Id : 0
2022-05-26 11:40:52.638 5308-5308/com.bipin.myapp I/InputMethodManager: startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
2022-05-26 11:40:52.645 5308-9485/com.bipin.myapp I/mobile-ffmpeg: Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/Test-Video.mp4':
2022-05-26 11:40:52.645 5308-9485/com.bipin.myapp I/mobile-ffmpeg:   Metadata:
2022-05-26 11:40:52.645 5308-9485/com.bipin.myapp I/mobile-ffmpeg:     major_brand     : 
2022-05-26 11:40:52.646 5308-9485/com.bipin.myapp I/mobile-ffmpeg: mp42
2022-05-26 11:40:52.646 5308-9485/com.bipin.myapp I/mobile-ffmpeg: 
2022-05-26 11:40:52.646 5308-9485/com.bipin.myapp I/mobile-ffmpeg:     minor_version   : 
2022-05-26 11:40:52.646 5308-9485/com.bipin.myapp I/mobile-ffmpeg: 1
2022-05-26 11:40:52.646 5308-9485/com.bipin.myapp I/mobile-ffmpeg: 
2022-05-26 11:40:52.646 5308-9485/com.bipin.myapp I/mobile-ffmpeg:     compatible_brands: 
2022-05-26 11:40:52.646 5308-9485/com.bipin.myapp I/mobile-ffmpeg: isommp41mp42
2022-05-26 11:40:52.646 5308-9485/com.bipin.myapp I/mobile-ffmpeg: 
2022-05-26 11:40:52.646 5308-9485/com.bipin.myapp I/mobile-ffmpeg:     creation_time   : 
2022-05-26 11:40:52.646 5308-9485/com.bipin.myapp I/mobile-ffmpeg: 2022-04-05T14:20:18.000000Z
2022-05-26 11:40:52.647 5308-9485/com.bipin.myapp I/mobile-ffmpeg: 
2022-05-26 11:40:52.647 5308-9485/com.bipin.myapp I/mobile-ffmpeg:   Duration: 
2022-05-26 11:40:52.647 5308-9485/com.bipin.myapp I/mobile-ffmpeg: 00:00:15.48
2022-05-26 11:40:52.647 5308-9485/com.bipin.myapp I/mobile-ffmpeg: , start: 
2022-05-26 11:40:52.647 5308-9485/com.bipin.myapp I/mobile-ffmpeg: 0.000000
2022-05-26 11:40:52.647 5308-9485/com.bipin.myapp I/mobile-ffmpeg: , bitrate: 
2022-05-26 11:40:52.647 5308-9485/com.bipin.myapp I/mobile-ffmpeg: 5255 kb/s
2022-05-26 11:40:52.647 5308-9485/com.bipin.myapp I/mobile-ffmpeg: 
2022-05-26 11:40:52.647 5308-9485/com.bipin.myapp I/mobile-ffmpeg:     Stream #0:0
2022-05-26 11:40:52.647 5308-9485/com.bipin.myapp I/mobile-ffmpeg: (und)
2022-05-26 11:40:52.647 5308-9485/com.bipin.myapp I/mobile-ffmpeg: : Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 540x960, 5251 kb/s
2022-05-26 11:40:52.647 5308-9485/com.bipin.myapp I/mobile-ffmpeg: , 
2022-05-26 11:40:52.647 5308-9485/com.bipin.myapp I/mobile-ffmpeg: 30.04 fps, 
2022-05-26 11:40:52.647 5308-9485/com.bipin.myapp I/mobile-ffmpeg: 30 tbr, 
2022-05-26 11:40:52.647 5308-9485/com.bipin.myapp I/mobile-ffmpeg: 600 tbn, 
2022-05-26 11:40:52.647 5308-9485/com.bipin.myapp I/mobile-ffmpeg: 1200 tbc
2022-05-26 11:40:52.647 5308-9485/com.bipin.myapp I/mobile-ffmpeg:  (default)
2022-05-26 11:40:52.648 5308-9485/com.bipin.myapp I/mobile-ffmpeg: 
2022-05-26 11:40:52.648 5308-9485/com.bipin.myapp I/mobile-ffmpeg:     Metadata:
2022-05-26 11:40:52.648 5308-9485/com.bipin.myapp I/mobile-ffmpeg:       creation_time   : 
2022-05-26 11:40:52.648 5308-9485/com.bipin.myapp I/mobile-ffmpeg: 2022-04-05T14:20:18.000000Z
2022-05-26 11:40:52.648 5308-9485/com.bipin.myapp I/mobile-ffmpeg: 
2022-05-26 11:40:52.648 5308-9485/com.bipin.myapp I/mobile-ffmpeg:       handler_name    : 
2022-05-26 11:40:52.648 5308-9485/com.bipin.myapp I/mobile-ffmpeg: Core Media Video
2022-05-26 11:40:52.648 5308-9485/com.bipin.myapp I/mobile-ffmpeg: 
2022-05-26 11:40:52.648 5308-9485/com.bipin.myapp I/mobile-ffmpeg: Stream mapping:
2022-05-26 11:40:52.648 5308-9485/com.bipin.myapp I/mobile-ffmpeg:   Stream #0:0 -> #0:0
2022-05-26 11:40:52.648 5308-9485/com.bipin.myapp I/mobile-ffmpeg:  (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
2022-05-26 11:40:52.648 5308-9485/com.bipin.myapp I/mobile-ffmpeg: 
2022-05-26 11:40:52.648 5308-9485/com.bipin.myapp I/mobile-ffmpeg: Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
2022-05-26 11:40:52.673 5308-9485/com.bipin.myapp W/mobile-ffmpeg: [graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0xb400007bf58e0ed0] sws_param option is deprecated and ignored
2022-05-26 11:40:52.674 5308-9485/com.bipin.myapp I/mobile-ffmpeg: [libx264 @ 0xb400007c65974720] using cpu capabilities: ARMv8 NEON
2022-05-26 11:40:52.678 5308-9485/com.bipin.myapp I/mobile-ffmpeg: [libx264 @ 0xb400007c65974720] profile High, level 3.0, 4:2:0, 8-bit
2022-05-26 11:40:52.678 5308-9485/com.bipin.myapp I/mobile-ffmpeg: [libx264 @ 0xb400007c65974720] 264 - core 160 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2020 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=19.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
2022-05-26 11:40:52.678 5308-9485/com.bipin.myapp I/mobile-ffmpeg: Output #0, mp4, to '/data/user/0/com.bipin.myapp/cache/Test-Video_16535454525974982000318197164476.mp4':
2022-05-26 11:40:52.678 5308-9485/com.bipin.myapp I/mobile-ffmpeg:   Metadata:
2022-05-26 11:40:52.678 5308-9485/com.bipin.myapp I/mobile-ffmpeg:     major_brand     : 
2022-05-26 11:40:52.678 5308-9485/com.bipin.myapp I/mobile-ffmpeg: mp42
2022-05-26 11:40:52.678 5308-9485/com.bipin.myapp I/mobile-ffmpeg: 
2022-05-26 11:40:52.678 5308-9485/com.bipin.myapp I/mobile-ffmpeg:     minor_version   : 
2022-05-26 11:40:52.678 5308-9485/com.bipin.myapp I/mobile-ffmpeg: 1
2022-05-26 11:40:52.679 5308-9485/com.bipin.myapp I/mobile-ffmpeg: 
2022-05-26 11:40:52.679 5308-9485/com.bipin.myapp I/mobile-ffmpeg:     compatible_brands: 
2022-05-26 11:40:52.679 5308-9485/com.bipin.myapp I/mobile-ffmpeg: isommp41mp42
2022-05-26 11:40:52.679 5308-9485/com.bipin.myapp I/mobile-ffmpeg: 
2022-05-26 11:40:52.679 5308-9485/com.bipin.myapp I/mobile-ffmpeg:     encoder         : 
2022-05-26 11:40:52.679 5308-9485/com.bipin.myapp I/mobile-ffmpeg: Lavf58.48.100
2022-05-26 11:40:52.679 5308-9485/com.bipin.myapp I/mobile-ffmpeg: 
2022-05-26 11:40:52.679 5308-9485/com.bipin.myapp I/mobile-ffmpeg:     Stream #0:0
2022-05-26 11:40:52.679 5308-9485/com.bipin.myapp I/mobile-ffmpeg: (und)
2022-05-26 11:40:52.679 5308-9485/com.bipin.myapp I/mobile-ffmpeg: : Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(bt709), 540x538, q=-1--1
2022-05-26 11:40:52.679 5308-9485/com.bipin.myapp I/mobile-ffmpeg: , 
2022-05-26 11:40:52.680 5308-9485/com.bipin.myapp I/mobile-ffmpeg: 30 fps, 
2022-05-26 11:40:52.680 5308-9485/com.bipin.myapp I/mobile-ffmpeg: 15360 tbn, 
2022-05-26 11:40:52.680 5308-9485/com.bipin.myapp I/mobile-ffmpeg: 30 tbc
2022-05-26 11:40:52.680 5308-9485/com.bipin.myapp I/mobile-ffmpeg:  (default)
2022-05-26 11:40:52.680 5308-9485/com.bipin.myapp I/mobile-ffmpeg: 
2022-05-26 11:40:52.680 5308-9485/com.bipin.myapp I/mobile-ffmpeg:     Metadata:
2022-05-26 11:40:52.680 5308-9485/com.bipin.myapp I/mobile-ffmpeg:       creation_time   : 
2022-05-26 11:40:52.680 5308-9485/com.bipin.myapp I/mobile-ffmpeg: 2022-04-05T14:20:18.000000Z
2022-05-26 11:40:52.680 5308-9485/com.bipin.myapp I/mobile-ffmpeg: 
2022-05-26 11:40:52.680 5308-9485/com.bipin.myapp I/mobile-ffmpeg:       handler_name    : 
2022-05-26 11:40:52.680 5308-9485/com.bipin.myapp I/mobile-ffmpeg: Core Media Video
2022-05-26 11:40:52.680 5308-9485/com.bipin.myapp I/mobile-ffmpeg: 
2022-05-26 11:40:52.680 5308-9485/com.bipin.myapp I/mobile-ffmpeg:       encoder         : 
2022-05-26 11:40:52.680 5308-9485/com.bipin.myapp I/mobile-ffmpeg: Lavc58.96.100 libx264
2022-05-26 11:40:52.681 5308-9485/com.bipin.myapp I/mobile-ffmpeg: 
2022-05-26 11:40:52.681 5308-9485/com.bipin.myapp I/mobile-ffmpeg:     Side data:
2022-05-26 11:40:52.681 5308-9485/com.bipin.myapp I/mobile-ffmpeg:       
2022-05-26 11:40:52.681 5308-9485/com.bipin.myapp I/mobile-ffmpeg: cpb: 
2022-05-26 11:40:52.682 5308-9485/com.bipin.myapp I/mobile-ffmpeg: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 
2022-05-26 11:40:52.684 5308-9485/com.bipin.myapp I/mobile-ffmpeg: vbv_delay: N/A
2022-05-26 11:40:52.684 5308-9485/com.bipin.myapp I/mobile-ffmpeg: 
2022-05-26 11:40:52.797 5308-5308/com.bipin.myapp D/[main;BaseDaggerFragment#onDestroyView:90]: Debug - PostMediaTabFragment onDestroyView called
2022-05-26 11:40:52.798 5308-5308/com.bipin.myapp D/[main;ViewBindingBaseFragment#onDestroyView:32]: Debug - PostMediaTabFragment onDestroyView called
2022-05-26 11:40:52.895 5308-9521/com.bipin.myapp A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), fault addr 0xb400007a53e6d000 in tid 9521 (RxCachedThreadS), pid 5308 (com.bipin.myapp)
2022-05-26 11:40:54.302 9524-9524/? A/DEBUG: Cmdline: com.bipin.myapp
2022-05-26 11:40:54.302 9524-9524/? A/DEBUG: pid: 5308, tid: 9521, name: RxCachedThreadS  >>> com.bipin.myapp <<<
2022-05-26 11:40:54.302 9524-9524/? A/DEBUG:       #00 pc 000000000058b8d0  /data/app/~~QE7_ItG7A3ZSxt4PIZf-2w==/com.bipin.myapp-o6_afbhi9zItP6DEnUAd6w==/base.apk!libavcodec.so
2022-05-26 11:40:54.398 1189-1447/? W/ActivityManager: Missing app error report, app = com.bipin.myapp crashing = true notResponding = false
2022-05-26 11:40:54.407 1189-9530/? W/ActivityManager: crash : com.bipin.myapp,10342
```